# Python error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character" in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

This is my MongoDB Database :

[image]

And with my python code, i want to print all Documents of Collection name "accessLog"
This is my Python Code (python 3.4)

```
import pymongo 
from pymongo import *
import datetime
import sys

client = MongoClient('MyDatabase')

print('-----Access to Database cdt_log------')
db = client['cdt_log']
print(db)

collection = db['accessLog']

for record in collection.find({}):
    print(record)
```

But I had error :
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0323' in position 369: character maps to undefined

How i can fix this code
Thanks very much !

Comment: add this lie : `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: I add line " # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- " but still error

Comment: you had error while `print(record)` or in `collection.find({})`?

Comment: I have error " print(record) "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unidecode` to convert unicode data to ASCII text and then print the record.

```
import unidecode
for record in collection.find({}):
     print unidecode.unidecode_expect_nonascii(record)
```

Comment: Thanks Tanu, with your suggestion i fix my code :  <pre>unidecode.unidecode_expect_nonascii(record['name'])  <code>          or i can add this : encode('utf-8) to my code : record['name'].encode('utf-8')